# Connection to Oracle database not working

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I am currently working on a project with someone. We are connecting to a oracle Database using the NuGet Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core.

We are connecting using a connection string that looks like this:

```
"User Id={this._dbUser};Password={this._dbPassword};Data Source={this._dbServer};"
```

The Parameters we pass on are correct we checked multiple times.

At first I got a Connection Timed out error which we fixed by adding `persist security info=false;Connection Timeout=120;` to the connection string.
At first it seemed to be working but then we encountered a new error.
This time it was saying:

```
Oracle communication: Connection to server could not be established or connection string not parsed
```

(Might not be 100% accurate because I had to translate it from German to English)

We could not find a solution for this error but we discovered that the error only gets thrown when we run the code on my machine. His is doing totally fine and can connect without any problems.

Could it be that I have some settings set on my machine that would prevent me from accessing the Database?

Comment: check firewall settings

Comment: try running **tnsping data-source-name** from the command prompt. What happens then?

Comment: We are both in the same network as the database (3 seperate machines)

Comment: @simonatrcl that is the output I get

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 05-DEZ-2019 13:35:11

Copyright (c) 1997, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Parameterdateien benutzt:
C:\app\client\PC-03\product\12.2.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Adapter HOSTNAME zur Aufl÷sung des Alias benutzt
Verbindungsversuch mit (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=wupi))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.168.0.61)(PORT=1521)))

Comment: As long as those are the correct details of the server where the database is, then this shows a) your machine has Oracle drivers installed ok b) and configured correctly. Which is a pity, as that's relatively easy to fix. If you've got something like Toad or SQLDeveloper installed, can you use it to connect to the database?

Comment: @simonatrcl with SQLDeveloper I can connect without a problem.

Comment: Possibility: add "integrated security=no" to the connection string. Can you edit the question giving a) the actual Oracle (ORA-xxx...) error code and b) the code where you set up and open the connection?

Comment: @simonatrcl, The `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` does not require any further drivers installed. SQLDeveloper is Java based an used completely different technology to connect to an Oracle Database.

Comment: How and where did you define the `TNS_ADMIN` variable?

Comment: Try to set your `NLS_LANG` variable to `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN`, then the error message should be in english,

Comment: Check the composition root .config file to ensure that the `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` section has a `<dataSource alias="{this._dbServer}" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION = /...">` that matches whatever `{this._dbServer}` is -